# 'Dataset' type for dictionary, but what does "Usage: Between 100 and 1000 domains" mean?

Tags: schema.org

I have an online dictionary website. I'm looking for a proper Schema.org type for it. Sadly there is no specific type for it (at least I couldn't find any). There is `Book`, `Article` that probably one of them would be a good choose in my case. Now I seen `Dataset` type, first of all, is it a good choice for an online dictionary website?

I don't want to use neither `Article` nor `Book` because they need `author`, `image` etc. properties that I don't have that data. That's why I think `Dataset` is a better choice.

The only doubt is about that **Usage** number. What does it mean? Between "100" and "1000" domains? What are those range numbers referring to?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### "Usage"

"Usage" are statistics how often a term (type or property) is used in a set of crawled web pages. This line doesn’t get displayed for terms that have no or only very few occurrences. The stats are rarely updated, and arguably not representative. I would suggest to ignore the "Usage" stats altogether.

#### Types for dictionary and dictionary terms

([links and examples in my answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52016562/1591669))

For dictionary terms, you might want to use `DefinedTerm`:

> Often used in the context of […] dictionaries, […]

For the whole dictionary, you might want to use `DefinedTermSet`:

> A set of defined terms for example a […] dictionary […]

#### Required properties

Note that Schema.org doesn’t require any properties. It’s perfectly fine to have an `Article` or a `Book` without `author` or `image` properties.

Consumers (like Google) might add requirements/recommendations, but these are only for getting one of their features. If you can’t provide all required data, you won’t get that feature, but you may still use the type.

Comment: Thank you .. so that "usage" number doesn't mean as a limitation in the number of URLs I'm allowed to use of that datatype? Also, ok I will use `DefinedTermSet` datatype, but what about `dataset`, isn't it good for a dictionary?

Comment: @MartinAJ: It could be argued that `DataFeed` (which is a sub-type of `Dataset`) is suitable for representing a dictionary -- not a perfect match as it’s meant for something else, but similar enough. But as `DefinedTermSet` is an explicit match, why look elsewhere? -- Only if you don’t want to use terms from Pending (`DefinedTerm` and  `DefinedTermSet` are still in Pending), you could consider using it instead for the meantime.

Comment: I see .. Can you please explain what does "Pending" mean exactly? It is not known as a registered datatype yet? Can't  google detect it?

Comment: @MartinAJ: Pending means that the terms are still under discussion/development. They might be moved to Core (in the next Schema.org release), they might be changed, they might be removed. Consumers should have no problem working with terms from Pending, but sometimes they need some time before they recognize new terms.

Comment: I have a related question, is it better to use schema-markup as microdata format or json-ld ? Or they are the same efficient in seo ?

Comment: Really? Pending means that?! emm, sounds using it is not stable .. what happens if all pages (each word of dictionary has a page in my website) got indexed and suddenly `DefinedTerm` removed/changed? then the SEO of my website will be broken? what would you use if you had a online dictionary website? either `DataFeed` or `DefinedTerm` ?

Comment: @MartinAJ: I’m not aware that `DataFeed` or `DefinedTermSet` would affect SEO in the first place, currently, so nothing could break. But if a consumer decides to make use of Pending terms, they will of course have a procedure what happens if these terms won’t get into Core (e.g., keep supporting them, or moving to an alternative). -- I would use the best matching term, no matter if in Pending or in Core, but for Pending terms I’ll check the status after the next Schema.org release, and then possibly adapt my markup.

Comment: @stack: That’s the wrong place to discuss this question. I think we had multiple questions about this topic. tl;dr: doesn’t matter, as long as the consumers you are interested in support the syntax.

Comment: Ok, I know here is not a good place to say this, but I don't have any other contact way with you. Actually I have a request. I'm the CEO of [lamtakam](https://lamtakam.com/about#team) website. It is a Q/A website almost the same as SE. People can [ask](https://lamtakam.com/qanda/ask/new), [answer](https://lamtakam.com/qanda/654/معنی+عبارت+When+you%26rsquo%3Bre+through+در+زبان+انگلیسی+چیست؟#post-654) and see [the questions list](https://lamtakam.com/questions). Our website has for Persian people who don't know English to use SE communities.

Comment: Well what's the request: we've launched our website last month, but google doesn't index us (though we will update our website in the next week that is included shcema), anyway, the SEO of our website is really bad. Actually we don't have a SEO-expert in our team. Also apparently you've lots of great skills in this field. Can you please join us? (as a consultant). We don't expect you write code for us, just we probably explain something for you to know your opinion about. That's it. Can you please do a favor and join us? Being you in our team gives us credit too.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Ideally you would ask the questions here on Webmasters SE, so everyone can answer and/or benefit from it :) For issues that can’t be publicly discussed, or for which SE’s Q/A model is not a good fit, feel free to contact me (I added an email address to [my profile](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/17633/unor?tab=profile)).